# Create a named empty list based on dataframe and column names

Tags: r, list, purrr

I want create an empty list which takes on the name of a dataframe and has empty elements inside based on the name of the dataframe

## What I've Tried - Does Not Work

```
my_list_function <- function(thedata) {
  list(
    x = map(names(x), ~ .x = list())
  ))
}
```

I want to be able to run

```
my_list_function(mtcars)
```

and get the output:

## Desired Output

```
list(
  mtcars = list(
    mpg = list(),
    cyl = list(),
    disp = list(),
    hp = list(),
    drat = list(),
    wt = list(),
    qseq = list(),
    vs = list(),
    am = list(),
    gear = list(),
    carb = list()
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
my_list_function <- function(data) {
     nm1 <- deparse(substitute(data))
    setNames(list( setNames(rep(list(list()), length(data)), names(data))), nm1)
      }

my_list_function(mtcars)
#$mtcars
#$mtcars$mpg
#list()

#$mtcars$cyl
#list()

#$mtcars$disp
#list()

#$mtcars$hp
#list()
# ...
```

---

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
my_list_function <- function(data) {


   lst(!! enquo(data) := map(data, ~ list()))
  }
my_list_function(mtcars)
#$mtcars
#$mtcars$mpg
#list()

#$mtcars$cyl
#list()

#$mtcars$disp
#list()

#$mtcars$hp
#list()
# ...
```

Comment: Typo with "lst" in the `purrr` answer. And I don't know if it is an `rlang` version thing or something but I get `Error: `:=` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument` as well (I had it in my solution at first and then it stopped working).

Comment: @Adam sorry, `lst` is found in both `tibble` and `dplyr`.  I should have updated it

Comment: Great. Works now. Good to know, that was effectively what I wanted to do but settled for `set_names()`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
map(mtcars, ~ list())
```

If you want the name of the data itself in the list, you can try this:

```r
my_list_function <- function(data) {
  .data <- rlang::enquo(data)

  list(map(data, ~ list())) %>% 
    set_names(rlang::as_name(.data))
}

my_list_function(mtcars)
```